# Resizing a button in Kivy layout file

Tags: python, kivy, widget

In my code, I'm resizing and trying to hide buttons while user is logged in. The problem is that Login button is not responding correctly for some unknown reason.

```py
Label:
    halign: 'center'
    valign: 'middle'
    text_size: self.size
    size_hint_x: .5
    text: root.text
PrimaryButton:
    text: "Manage" if (root.text != '') else ""
    size_hint_x: .25 if (root.text != '') else 0
    opacity: 1 if (root.text != '') else 0
    disabled: False if (root.text != '') else True
    on_release:
        root.logout() if (root.text != '') else root.changeScreen("AccountCreation")
        root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
PrimaryButton:
    text: "Log Out" if (root.text != '') else "Log In"
    size_hint_x: .25 if (root.text != '') else .5
    on_release:
        root.logout() if (root.text != '') else root.changeScreen("AccountCreation")
        root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
```

###### Not logged in:

[image: Not logged in]

###### Logged in:

[image: Logged in]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, first button should have this parameters -

size_hint: (.25, 1) if (root.text != '') else (None, 1)

width: 0 if (root.text != '') else 0